# Freeing memory, Windows has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a problem when I try to free the allocated memory for matrices in my code.
I'm using this function:

```
void free_matrix(float **m, int row)
{
    for( int i=0; i<row; i++ ) 
    {
        free( m[i]);
    }
    free(m);

}
```

But I don't know why it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in mycode.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in mycode.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while mycode.exe has focus.
```

Comment: Please show how you are using the matrix `m`. I am pretty sure the error is not in this code snippet, although Visual Studio may actually pop the error message while in this function...

Comment: Please let us see the allocation code. i.e. your malloc calls.

Comment: Using a proper class would fix this. Even `std::vector<std::vector<float> >` is better than `float**`.

Comment: @MSalters depending on the situation, the vector will use more memory, it will usually reallocate too frequently and it has more overhead. Also, the OP may not be allowed to use stl.

Comment: @JonathanHenson: If you pass the same size to vector as you'd pass to new, it won't reallocate at all. And if the OP may not use STL, he should fix that problem first.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are freeing memory that hasn't been allocated. Check the code where you allocate the memory, or better yet, post it for us to see. Make sure you are only calling free on valid pointers. Also, make sure you aren't mismatching "new" with "free".

Comment: or a location is free'd twice.

Comment: @TobiasLangner that is possible but seems unlikely judging by the freeMatrix code the OP posted.

Comment: I just wanted to add it for completeness. Someone might search for this problem and find this post - although it will not help him with his specific problem, the reason why this happens in general might help him.

Comment: @TobiasLangner Thanks for that. The reason it isn't more specific is because the OP has yet to be more specific.